# Measure App Installs using Facebook Ad campaign

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am currently working on Facebook ad campaign, I would like to get the total number of application download for Android and iPhone specifically from this Facebook campaign.

After going through complete sets of documents provided by Facebook i could not conclude whether there is a need of any client side i.e. Android and Iphone implementations.

All the install button click in the ads would redirect the user to there respective app store.

The method provided by facebbok will consider each first launch as a fresh install even if it from Play or App store.

So how do i track the exact count for number of installs via my facebook ad campaign and what are the things that need to considered at the client side.

If any one is aware about it or if any developer has worked upon same thing, looking forward for any help or information.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook's ad products and not Facebook's Ads API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track your Mobile App Installs and correlate them with your Facebook Ads campaign, then unfortunately you DO need to integrate with the Facebook SDK.  If you attempt to use URL tracking parameters, they will get stripped out by Facebook.